# Integral of irrational function

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}}{x-2}dx
$$

I tried:
$$
t =x-2
$$
$$
dt = dx
$$
but it didn't work.
Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y=x-2$ and integrate by parts to get

$$\int dx \: \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}}{x-2} = -2 (x-2)^{-1/2} (x+1)^{1/2} + \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y (y+3)}}$$

In the second integral, complete the square in the denominator to get

$$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y (y+3)}} = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{(y+3/2)^2-9/4}}$$

This integral may be solved using a substitution $y+3/2=3/2 \sec{\theta}$, $dy = 3/2 \sec{\theta} \tan{\theta}$.  Using the fact that

$$\int d\theta \sec{\theta} = \log{(\sec{\theta}+\tan{\theta})}+C$$

we may evaluate the integral exactly.  I leave the intervening steps to the reader; I get

$$\int dx \: \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}}{x-2} = -2 (x-2)^{-1/2} (x+1)^{1/2} + \log{\left[\frac{2}{3}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-1}\right]}+C$$

Comment: Note that $log$ part could be simplified as $$\log\left[2x-1 + \sqrt{(2x-1)^2-1}\right]-\log 3$$ and you can merge the $-\log 3$ into the constant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: this is true.  Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, should be $\sqrt{(2x-1)^2-9}$ in my simplification.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: s'OK.  I got the point.

Comment: Also note that the first term is $-2\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}$, which suggest the other substitution (the one that I took below.)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$\frac{x+1}{x-2} = 1 + \frac{3}{x-2}$$

The substitution can be done then as $u=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}$, which can be written as $x=\frac{3}{u^2-1}+2$. The resulting integral is a little messy, but avoids trigonometric substitutions.

You end up with the simple:
$$\int \left(-2 +\frac{1}{u+1}-\frac{1}{u-1}\right)du$$

Yielding: $$-2u + \log{\frac{u+1}{u-1}} + C$$

You can, with some work, see that $\frac{u+1}{u-1}$ is actually the same value as inside the log in the other answer above, by writing it as $\frac{(u+1)^2}{u^2-1}$ and replacing values. In paricular, $u^2=1+\frac{3}{x-2}$. You get $$\frac{u+1}{u-1} = \frac{2x-1 + 2\sqrt{(x+1)(x-2)}}{3}$$

**Note**

You could first do the substitution $v=\frac{1}{x-2}$ which is the substitution most obvious from my hint, getting $x=2+\frac{1}{v}$. You end up with:

$$-\int \frac{\sqrt{3v+1}}{v}dv$$

But from there, you really need to substitute $w=\sqrt{3v+1}$ to get an integral, and that $w$ is the same as our original $u$. Still, might be easier to do it in two steps.

Comment: I see.  Although I am not sure why anyone would want to avoid trig substitution.  Is it harder, or more work, or just...icky?

Comment: Trig substitutions need more knowledge is all. This problem can be solved if your book hasn't covered trig function derivatives and substitutions. Not really icky - I probably prefer the above answer, actually. @RonGordon

Comment: Perhaps you are right...but by the time one is presented with an integral such as this, I would hope that trig substitution is not foreign.

Comment: But the key realization, and really the reason I posted my answer, is that you can determine $x$ from $\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}}$. $\frac{x+1}{x-2}$ hides a "nice" function, and we can use that.

Comment: Absolutely - and BTW I like how you attacked this, sort of a challenge to avoid trig sub.